# SVG text elements render very large in Firefox and IE9, but they look perfect in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have text elements inside of SVG files like this:

```
<text style="font-family: "TrajanPro-Regular"; fill: #010101;" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 60.5264 40.834)">

<text style="font-family: "TimesNewRomanPSMT";" transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 18.3101 247.167)">
```

In Chrome and Safari, everything looks great, but in Firefox and IE9 the text is absolutely gigantic.  What is going on in those browsers that causes it to be different?

Comment: Can you possibly provide a complete example?

Comment: a) As you can see above, you have invalid markup there; the style attribute's value ends right before "Trajan due to the double-quote. b) You are explicitly not setting the font-size for the `<text>`?